# No reasonable solution for cylindrical waveguide using FreeFEM++

Tags: finite-element

I am using [FreeFEM++](https://freefem.org/) to simulate the cylindrical waveguide, but no reasonable solution is returned. Here I'm using the 94 GHz light ($\lambda$ = 3.17mm) as input, and radius of the waveguide is 1.27mm.

If more information is needed to be posted, just reply and I will provide it as soon as possible.

UPDATE:

- As is pointed out in the comment, I must clarify that *no reasonable solution* means that FreeFEM++ returned without error, but the solution is empty or NaN, which means the output of `cout << "r = " << r << " Integrated Ex = " << int3d(Th)(abs(Ex)^2) << endl;` is either `0` or `nan`.
- It seems I have to clarify the boundary conditions. The light travels from one base to the other base. From the [example](https://github.com/FreeFem/FreeFem-sources/blob/master/examples/plugin/waveguide.edp) from FreeFEM++, the boundary conditions are:
  $$\begin{aligned}
  -k^2 E + \nabla\times (\nabla\times E) = 0 &\qquad \text{inside the body} \\
  E \times n = 0 &\qquad \text{on the side} \\
  (\nabla \times E) \times n + i\beta n \times (E \times n) = G_{inc} &\qquad \text{on the lower base}\\
  (\nabla \times E) \times n + i\beta n \times (E \times n) = 0 &\qquad \text{on the upper base}
  \end{aligned}$$
  where $k$ is the wavenumber, $n$ is the outward unit normal, $\beta = \sqrt{k^2 - (m\pi/r)^2 - (n\pi/r)^2}$ (m and n are number of half waves)

  no periodic boundary conditions are used and no specific BCs is set for the edges.

Here is the code:

```
// heavily copied from https://github.com/FreeFem/FreeFem-sources/blob/master/examples/plugin/waveguide.edp

load "MUMPS"
load "iovtk"
load "medit"
load "msh3"
load "Element_Mixte3d"

// The boundary value problem:
// (sigma = 0, here k is the wavenumber) 
//  -k^2*E + curl(curl E) = 0   in Omega
//  E x n = 0   on the side
//  Curl(E) x n + i*beta n x (E x n) = Ginc   on z = 0
//  Curl(E) x n + i*beta n x (E x n) = 0      on z = c

bool debug = true;

real r    = 0.00127;
real d    = r;
int  nx   = 20;
int  nz   = 20;
real zmin = 0.0;
real zmax = 0.01;

// build the mesh
border C(t=0.0, 2.0*pi) {
    x=r*cos(t);
    y=r*sin(t);
    label=1;
};
mesh Thx = buildmesh(C(nx));

int [int] rup = [0, 1], rdown = [0, 2], rmid = [1, 3];
int guide = 3, in = 1, out = 2;
mesh3 Th = buildlayers(Thx, nz, zbound=[zmin, zmax]
        , coef = 1.
        , labelup = rup
        , labelmid = rmid
        , labeldown = rdown
        );
//medit("Cyl", Th, wait=debug);
//plot(Th, wait=debug);

cout << "labels(Th) = " << labels(Th) << endl;

real f  = 94*10^9;
real er = 1;
real c0 = 299792458;
real k  = 2*pi*f*sqrt(er) / c0;
int m = 1, n = 1;
real beta = sqrt(k^2 - (m*pi/d)^2 - (n*pi/d)^2);
real Z = sqrt(er) * 120 * pi;

real ukb = 1 / (k^2 - beta^2);
func expbz = exp(-1i*beta*z);
func ExTE = (1i*k*Z) * ukb * (n*pi) / d * cos(m*pi*x/d) * sin(n*pi*y/d) * expbz;
func EyTE = -(1i*k*Z) * ukb * (n*pi) / d * sin(m*pi*x/d) * cos(n*pi*y/d) * expbz;

func Gix = +2*1i*beta*ExTE;
func Giy = +2*1i*beta*EyTE;
func Giz = 0;


fespace Nh(Th, Edge13d);
Nh<complex> [Ex, Ey, Ez], [vx, vy, vz];

// Macros
macro Curl(ux,uy,uz) [dy(uz)-dz(uy),dz(ux)-dx(uz),dx(uy)-dy(ux)] // EOM
macro Nvec(ux,uy,uz) [uy*N.z-uz*N.y,uz*N.x-ux*N.z,ux*N.y-uy*N.x] // EOM //uxN 
macro Curlabs(ux,uy,uz) [abs(dy(uz)-dz(uy)),abs(dz(ux)-dx(uz)),abs(dx(uy)-dy(ux))] //EOM

problem waveguide([Ex, Ey, Ez], [vx, vy, vz], solver=sparsesolver) =
      int3d(Th)(Curl(Ex,Ey,Ez)' * Curl(vx,vy,vz))
    - int3d(Th)(k^2*[Ex,Ey,Ez]' * [vx, vy, vz])
    + int2d(Th,in,out)(1i * beta * Nvec(Ex,Ey,Ez)' * Nvec(vx,vy,vz))
    - int2d(Th,in)([vx,vy,vz]' * [Gix,Giy,Giz])
    + on(guide,Ex=0,Ey=0,Ez=0);

waveguide;

cout << "r = " << r << " Integrated Ex = " << int3d(Th)(abs(Ex)^2) << endl;
medit("real", Th, [real(Ex),real(Ey),real(Ez)]);
//cout << (abs(Ex)^2) << end;
//cout << (abs(Ey)^2) << end;
//cout << (abs(Ez)^2) << end;

//int[int] Order = [1];
//savevtk("result_x.vtu", Th, abs(real(Ex)), dataname="RealEx", order=Order);
//savevtk("result_y.vtu", Th, abs(real(Ey)), dataname="RealEy", order=Order);
//savevtk("result_z.vtu", Th, abs(real(Ez)), dataname="RealEz", order=Order);
//medit("real", Th, [real(Ex),real(Ey),real(Ez)]);
```

and the log: [click here](https://pastebin.com/JVdS5zA3)

The model of cylindrical waveguide:
[image]

Comment: A good guide is to be specific with describing what happens. Here, that means to be explicit about what "but no reasonable solution is returned" actually means.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your kind advice. I have updated my problem and the term `no reasonable solution` should be clarified already. If there is still something unclear, just reply without hesitation.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Some ideas: What are your boundary conditions? For a waveguide you'd want dirichlet (=0) condition at the outside of the tubes and no BC at its ends. How about the degrees of freedom laying at the edge, are they free or constrained? Do you use periodic BC for the ends? Why do you need a 3D sim instead of a 2D sim?

Comment: 0 or NaN indeed seems wrong. But that's a question best asked on the FreeFEM forums.

Comment: @MPIchael Thanks for your questions, and I've updated the problem and added the explanation for the boundary conditions. As for the last idea, I'm just following FreeFEM++'s example and just be curious about if it still work on another shape of waveguide.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Maybe, if there is no good comments or answers here, I would consider to ask on their forum. Thanks for your advice.